# Is ExoPlayer supported in Android automotive apps?

Tags: android, automotive

hey guys I need your help, we are currently develop an android automotive application, and we have a part in it that will play a music/media from HLS, HTTP LIVE STREAMING, and we use as an initial decision ExoPlayer, but we have some fears in the futures, about if it's compatible with android automotive? or if it's work fine without play services.

have any one previous experience with something like this ?

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to Android Auto (reasonably common, but the app runs on the phone and uses the car for output) or Android Automotive (Android apps run on the car itself, but right now is limited to just a few car models)?

Comment: @CommonsWare no I mean android automotive, run on the car itself

Answer (score 0):

I think it is highly depend on which IVI system your app intended to be running on.
Still now we dont have any similar to Google Play for IVI android based yet. Since it will be a long story between OEM and Google..
Currently IVI (In vehicle Infotainment system ) android based is highly customized by OEM what allowed to be run on IVI is always decided by OEM.. Regrading many policies, Safety, Security rule...
So until we have that common rule clearly (just like common Android API SDK)..
The answer is not a "Yes"